# Beamer : several \input files

Tags: beamer, input

A would like to make several lectures, and I had organized the main file as follow :

```
%*********************************************************************
%*** Document maître de l'ensemble destiné au cahier des charges  ***
%*********************************************************************

\documentclass[article,compress,aspectratio=169,10pt]{beamer}% Les diapositives ont des dimensions 16:9

\usepackage{multimedia} %pour inclusion de vidéos

\input{/home/denis/Plantillas/laTeX/preambules/preambule_graph.tex}
\input{/home/denis/Plantillas/laTeX/preambules/preambule_tableaux_math_fr.tex}
\input{/home/denis/Plantillas/laTeX/preambules/preambule_base_fr.tex}

\author{Denis Quatrelivre}

\title[L'eau : facteur déterminant de l'agriculture]{La gestion de l’eau un facteur déterminant de l’agriculture méditerranéenne}
\subtitle{Selon le cahier des charges du comité régional VIVEA}

\institute[FluxdO]{
    S.A.S.U PolHyPro ing. - FluxdO\\
    {\large \textbf{hydrologie et hydroinformatique}}\\
    Gestion de projets}
\date{\today}

\graphicspath{%
    {/home/denis/fichiers_de_travail/hydro/Images/}
    {./build/images/}
    {./amages/}
    {/home/denis/fichiers_de_travail/hydro/Formations-conferences/cours_rural/build/images/}
}
% ************************ Commandes macros *************************************************
\newcommand{\puceetoile}[1]{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[every loop/.style={}]
    \draw (0,0) to [loop above] () to [loop right] ()
    to [loop below] () to [loop left] ();
    \end{tikzpicture}
}
\newcommand{\Fin}{%
    node[xshift=-1.5ex,rotate=10]{F}
    node[rotate=170]{i}
    node[xshift=1.5ex,rotate=45]{n}
}
%Le logo
\pgfdeclareimage    [width=0.15\paperwidth] {le-logo}   {/home/denis/fichiers_de_travail/hydro/Images/logo.png} 
\logo{
    \pgfuseimage{le-logo}
}
%%Le fond en goutte d'eau
%\pgfdeclareimage[width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight]{fddiapo}{
%\tikz      \filldraw [fill=white] (0.0) rectangle (\textwidth,\textheight);
%   \tikz \shade (0,0) rectangle (16,9);
%}
%\pgfdeclaremask{fdgoutte}{/home/denis/fichiers_de_travail/hydro/Images/bg_goutte-d-eau}
%\pgfimage[mask=fdgoutte,height=\paperheight,width=\paperwidth]{rectblanc}
\pgfdeclareimage[height=\paperheight,width=\paperwidth]{fd_goutte}{/home/denis/fichiers_de_travail/hydro/Images/bg_goutte-d-eau}

% ************************ Config de beamer *************************************************
\usetheme{EastLansing}
    %Antibes}
    %PaloAlto}
    %EastLansingheme{Antibes}}
    %PaloAlto}
    %EastLansing}
\setbeamercovered{transparent}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\setbeamercolor{background canvas}{bg=blue!30}%
\setbeamertemplate{blocks}[rounded][shadow=true]
\usefonttheme{structuresmallcapsserif,serif}
\setbeamercovered{dynamic}
\useinnertheme{rounded} %Des boules pour marquer les élements de liste

%Annonce de chaque partie en leur début
%\AtBeginPart{
%   \usebackgroundtemplate{bg=\pgfuseimage{fd_goutte}}%Utilisation de l'arrière plan goutte d'eau
%   \frame{\partpage}
%           \\
%           \tableofcontents
%       %   \tableofcontents[sectionstyle=show,subsectionstyle=hide]
%       %   \usebackgroundtemplate{bg=blue!40}
%}
% Table des matières au début de chaque section :
%\AtBeginSection % Do nothing for \section*
%{
%   \begin{frame}{Section : \insertsection}
%       \tableofcontents %[currentsection]
%   \end{frame}
%}

%**********************************************************************************************

%\includeonlylecture{gestion}
%\includeonlylecture{gerer}
%\includeonlylecture{tech_agri}

\begin{document}
 \AtBeginNote{\insertslideintonotes{0.25}\par} %Sur les pages de notes, une mignature occupant 25% de l'espace représente le transparent lié à la note.

%Titre, organisme
    \begin{frame}[plain]{}
            \titlepage
            \bigskip
            \texttt{\url{fluxdo@dennet.eu}}\hfill\pgfuseimage{le-logo}
    \end{frame}

%\lecture [La législation de l'eau] {Organisation institutionnelle de la gestion de leau, une démocratie ?} {gestion}
\input{eau_enjeux_gestion}

%\lecture[Le partage de l'eau]{Les raisons de partager l'eau, de la gérer en commun}{gestion}
\input{gerer_raisonner}

%\lecture[Les bonnes pratiques]{Usage de l'eau en agriculture}{tech_agri}
\input{pratiques_culturales}

\end{document}
```

I have tried to write the `\lectures{}` lines inside the files instead of the main one.
Now here are the preambules....
`preambule_graph.tex`

```
\usepackage{graphicx}
%\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[table,svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{pgf}
\usepgflibrary{shapes.callouts}
\usepgflibrary{shapes.misc}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric,arrows,spy,graphs,decorations}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing,calc,shadows.blur,fadings}
\usetikzlibrary{mindmap,shadows}

\usepackage{smartdiagram}
\usesmartdiagramlibrary{additions}

\usepackage{chronosys}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{picins}

\graphicspath{
    {/home/denis/fichiers_de_travail/hydro/Images/}
    {../../Images/}
    {./images/}
    {images/}
    {/home/denis/fichiers_de_travail/hydro/Formations-conferences/Eau_territoires_societes/images}
}
\unitlength=1cm
%Définition de couleurs
\definecolor{bleu1}{rgb}{0.3,0.3,1}
\definecolor{bleubord}{rgb}{0.2,0.2,0.6}
```

`preambule_tableaux_math_fr.tex`

```
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
%\usepackage[table,svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{multirow,booktabs} %joindre les cellules sur plusieurs lignes, filets spéciaux
```

`preambule_base_fr.tex`

```
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
%\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}%T1 est le nouveau standard de Latex pour le codage de caractères
\usepackage[francais]{babel}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}%Définition des en-têtes et pieds de page
%\pagestyle{fancy}%Active les en-têtes et pieds de page
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{eurosym}
\usepackage{numprint}%Mise en forme des nombre \numprint{nombre}
\usepackage{lmodern}%Police de caractère Latin moderne adaptée pour les pdf
\usepackage{microtype}%Meilleure typographie
%\usepackage{background}
%\usepackage[left=1.5cm, right=1.5cm, top=1.50cm, bottom=1.50cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{enumitem}

%\usepackage{pgf}
%http://texblog.org/2011/07/06/printing-multiple-pages-on-one-with-pgfpages/
%\usepackage{pgfpages} % Mise en page des pdf
%\pgfpagesuselayout{4 on 1}[a4paper,border shrink=5mm,landscape]

%\usepackage[tt]{titlepic}
\makeindex

\usepackage{hyperref}%Gère les liens dans le document pdf géńeré sous pdflatex
```

The result is the the pdflatex only compile the first one only (eau_enjeux_gestion in this case). Is there any reason for that ?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: Sorry, I did not thought the problem may come from the preambules.

Comment: Are you sure you don't have a `\end{document}` in the file `eau_...`? You should try to reduce your problem to the minimum set of small files that show it; I normally found the solution myself in that process... ;-)b

Comment: Yes. Definitely sure.